# xCode does not see X11 header files

Tags: header-files, x11

Running xCode 4.6.3

I have my X11 header files stored in the following path:

/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11

I have a .cp file and include X11/X.h

Error shows X11/X.h file not found.

Have tried putting path /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11 where these files are located under Targets>Search Paths>Header Search Paths but with no success.

Can someone explain where to put this path so that xCode can find the file?

\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had used the incorrect search path. There are two of them in Xcode.

To get these files recognized, I clicked the Project Name > Target Under Build Settings I went to Search Paths > User Header Search Paths > /Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/MESA/Mesa-9.1.5/include/

Also selected the recursive option. This allowed Xcode to see the files.